# Make a listview programmatically selectable only

Tags: android, listview

I have a `Listview` in a `Fragment`, and when I click an item a new `Fragment` is shown.

The problem is that for few milliseconds i can see the item selected by the touch. Is there a way to make these `Listview` programmatically selectable only? For example when I return to the `Fragment` and something connected is running (i already know how to select an item in Java, i just need to know how to disable touch clicks).

The item is colored with a selector and the `Listview`s are set to choice mode single.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to  implement the `ontouchListener()` of the fragment, and rewrite the `onTouch()` method with a simple:
`return false` 
to consume the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this quite easily. The two ways that are on top of my head are :

1. Disable touch on the list.
2. Put your ListView in a RelativeLayout (rootLayout) in the RelativeLayout(rootLayout) first item should be your ListView and the second can be another RelativeLayout(coverLyt) with height and width set as match_parent and **clickable set to true**. This will make the coverLyt take the touch events instead of your ListView. When you want the listView touch events to work set coverLyt's visibility to gone and visible when vice versa.